# How do I display posts from most ''recent custom taxonomy'' dynamically in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am presently working on a WordPress Journal Theme and I would like to know the best way to 
1. Sort the articles (a custom post type) based on Volumes and Issues (e.g., Volume 1 Issue 1, Volume 1 Issue 2 or Volume 1 Issue 3).
2. Display the current issue on the homepage (e.g., Volume 1 Issue 3)

**What I have done so far**
1. I created a custom taxonomy (Volume and Issues) and a custom field type (taxonomy) using ACF which  I linked  together. With the code below, I was able to display all posts in the taxonomy irrespective of whether they are in Volume 1 Issue 1, Volume 1 Issue 2 or Volume 1 Issue 3.

```
       <?php

  $homepageArticles = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page'        =>  -1,
        'post_type'             =>  'article',
        'meta_key'              =>  'current_issue',
        'orderby'               =>  'meta_value',

   ));

    while($homepageArticles->have_posts()){
        $homepageArticles->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="j-header shadow">

                <div class= "j-category"> <?php the_field('article_category'); ?>
        </div>

                    <div class="j-section">
                        <div class="j-article-thumbnail ">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="j-article-excerpts jp-excerpt ">
                            <div class="j-title">
                               <h1 class='j-title'><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 
                                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                                   </a></h1>

                            </div>
                            <div class="j-authors"> <span>By: </span>     
                           <?php the_field('authors'); ?></div>
                            <div id="mini-navbar">
                                <ul class="mini-navbar">
                                    <li><a href="#">Abstract</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">HTML Full Text</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php the_field('uplaod_pdf'); ?>">PDF</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>


<?php
    } wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

2. I also tries filtering the posts using meta_query using the second code but I got confused when it was time for me to compare the variables I created`

   ```
   $currentIssue = get_field('current_issue');
   $pastIssue = get_field('current_issue');
   ```

   $homepageArticles = new WP_Query(array(
           'posts_per_page'        =>  -1,
           'post_type'             =>  'article',
           'meta_key'              =>  'current_issue',
           'orderby'               =>  'meta_value',
           'meta_query'            =>  array(
               array(
                   'key'           =>  $currentIssue,
                   'compare'       =>  '>',
                   'value'         =>  $pastIssue
               )
           )

   ```
   ));

   while($homepageArticles->have_posts()){
       $homepageArticles->the_post(); ?>
   <div class="j-header shadow">

               <div class= "j-category"> <?php the_field('article_category'); ?>
       </div>

                   <div class="j-section">
                       <div class="j-article-thumbnail ">
                           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></a>
                       </div>
                       <div class="j-article-excerpts jp-excerpt ">
                           <div class="j-title">
                              <h1 class='j-title'><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 
                                   <?php the_title(); ?>
                                  </a></h1>

                           </div>
                           <div class="j-authors"> <span>By: </span>     
                          <?php the_field('authors'); ?></div>
                           <div id="mini-navbar">
                               <ul class="mini-navbar">
                                   <li><a href="#">Abstract</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">HTML Full Text</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="<?php the_field('uplaod_pdf'); ?>">PDF</a></li>
                               </ul>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>

                   <div class="clearfix"></div>
               </div>
   ```

   `

I would also like to know if there is a better way to sort articles based volumes and Issues in WordPress

Answer (score 0):

```
  $homepageArticles = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page'        =>  -1,
    'post_type'             =>  'article',
    'orderby'               =>  'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'fabric_building_types', //Change taxonomy name*/
            'field' => 'term_id', 
            'terms' => $cat->term_id, // Change it with terms it 
        )
    )
```

));
 Try with this